# Unusual Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation

$$y''y+n(y')^2=0\tag 1$$

I haven't found any references to equations of this type by searching.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to proceed?

It comes about from the following progression:

$$y=(y')^n-\frac 1n\tag 2\\
y'=ny''(y')^{n-1}\implies1=ny''(y')^{n-2}\\
0=n(n-2)(y'')^2(y')^{n-3}+ny'''(y')^{n-2}\\
0=(n-2)(y'')^2+y'''y'$$

Taking $y$ in place of $y'$ and $n$ in place of $n-2$ I get the form shown in $(1)$.  Are there any good ways to solve any of the other intermediate forms, or even the initial form shown in $(2)$?

Further constraints:

$y(0)\approx 1.27$ is an otherwise-unknown constant that I am attempting to build an expression for.

The initial problem is the recurrence relation with $a_1\approx 1.27$ the unknown constant and

$$a_{n+1}=(a_n)^{n+1}-\frac 1{n+1}$$

with the additional constraint $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$.

Comment: Hm, it's not evident that the problem is correctly posed. This might very well be the case where the $\lim=1$ for all initial values (or an interval of them).

Comment: I think $a_1\approx 1.27$ is the only solution that is monotone-decreasing for this sequence.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: Good point!  I didn't think of that...  The only differences are the limitation to real numbers and the increasing exponent between iterations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about doing these:

$$y'=u\to y''=u\frac{du}{dy}$$ and so $$y''y+n(y')^2=0\to u(u'(y)y+nu)=0$$

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this a bit further?  I'm not following what the next step might be...

Comment: It gives us $y'=0$ or we have $\frac{du}{u}=\frac{-n}{y}$. This is a separable ODE.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense now, thus giving the above solution $\ln y'=-n\ln y+c$.  And then perhaps one more step to evaluate?

Comment: @abiessu: Yes. ${}$

Comment: @B.S.: You made it easy to understand +1

Comment: @Amzoti: And for you in return. +++

Answer (score 1):

For Cauchy problem with initial data in zero you can multiply everything by $(n+1)y^{n-1}(t)$ because, as you say, the initial data is not zero. You get $$(y^{n+1})''=0,$$ therefore, $y^{n+1}(t)=a+bt$. Now you solve for $a$, $b$, which should give

$$y(t) = \left(y^{n+1}(0)+t(n+1)y^{n/(n+1)}(0)y'(0)\right)^{1/(n+1)}.$$

Comment: The difficulty with this is that $y(0)$ is an undefined constant ($\approx 1.27$) that I am attempting to solve for...

Comment: So, if you want to find $y(0)$, then what data do you have initially? Values in other points? Estimations of behaviour?

Comment: I edited the question to include the sequence where I got the problem; the limit of my sequence is $\lim a_n=1$ for recurrence $a_{n+1}=(a_n)^{n+1}-\frac 1{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

hint: as long as $yy' \ne 0$ you can divide through by it, giving:
$$\frac{y''}{y'} + n\frac{y'}{y} = 0
$$ 
giving $ln\; y' = -n \;ln \; y + c$

Comment: Does the next step go like this: $\frac {y'}{y^n}=e^c$ and thus $-\frac 1{y^{n-1}}=e^{c_1}x+c_2$?